# What do I need to correctly request chat websocket auth?

Tags: support, chat, login, stack-exchange-openid

I'm (attempting) to build an SE chat library in Ruby, since it's one of the few languages that doesn't yet seem to have one (Brainf**k, anyone?).

As part of that, I need to make a request to `http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ws-auth` to get the URL for a websocket.

This route requires a `roomid` parameter set to the room ID, and an `fkey` parameter set to your user fkey.

However, with all of those things set, I get a 404 from the route (and yes, I know it exists - I've checked it with a JS console hit from the browser). I suspect it's because I'm missing a cookie or two. The only cookie I currently have/am sending for `chat.stackoverflow.com` is `.ASPXBrowserOverride`, which sounds more to do with ASPX error pages than chat's functionality. I have previously authenticated with Stack Exchange OpenID, and have the `usr` cookie for that, and with `stackoverflow.com` (using SE OpenID).

What other cookies do I need to be sending? Is there anything else I need?

Comment: You'll need at least the acct cookie as well. If you didn't store that one earlier, you should. And I see one cookie i don't recall: chatusr.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same issue

Comment: I'm sure I did, @TimCastelijns, but I can't remember how... I'd suggest taking a look at existing libraries for a reference - [ChatX](https://github.com/thesecretmaster/ChatX) may be a good starting point